# hyperjaxb binding customization exclude package

Tags: binding, customization, hyperjaxb

I have an A.xsd that import a Common.xsd (name space eg. "http://common.pack"), then I would to exclude the contribution (jsut jpa annotations)  of Common.xsd to pack.common package but I need other xsd that have same namespace can stil contriute to pack.common package .

I am using this excerpt from my bindinds.xml :

```
 <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="CSG_Schemas\MultiMissionProtocol\MultiMissionCommon.xsd" node="/xs:schema" >
    <jaxb:schemaBindings >
            <jaxb:package name="pack.com package"/>
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>
    <hj:ignored-package name="pack.com package"/>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

but when run maven , it seems xjc delete the pack.common completely ,instead I want to block only entities coming from common.xsd

when I am wrong ?

Comment: need some more information. It would be good to know what errors you are seeing with this issue (as well as a way to reproduce it).

Comment: there isn't an error ,just I need to limit JPA produced annotation because I want to persist only the first levels of main classes . For example A.xsd will produced a (jaxb) A.class annotated (hj) with jpa annotation.A.class contain fields coming from common.xsd jaxb unmarshalling and the also these fields are annotated with jpa .Then I need to avoid jpa annotation for all A.class fileds.Now I wrote the binding excerpt to solve this but compilation exclude at all the common package , there are some classes in common package (namespace) coming from other xsd than common.xsd